# ShareTarget UWP

Tags: navigation, win-universal-app, share

I'm add Share Target to my UWP application. I have system back button in the top of this share view. And also I have two page. How can I override this back button to navigate back? Now it close share by my application. 
[image: share bar]

And can I hide this panel or change style?

Best regards, Dmitriy

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. Also you are not supposed to have multiple pages for sharing. Sharing expirience is consider to be as simple as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can't override that behavior.
As max you can subscribe to below events so that you will be notified when user taps on BACK button on share target window

```
Window.Current.Closed += Current_Closed;


Window.Current.VisibilityChanged += Current_VisibilityChanged;
```